# Finding distribution of $\frac{1}{\sqrt X}$ when $X$ is uniform on $[1,9]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I haven't been able to figure this question out and have been googling for about a good hour so thought I should post this here.

> Let $X$ be a $\mathrm{uniform}(1,9)$ random variable, i.e. it has the probability density function
>   $$
>   f_X(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 1/8,  & \text{if 1 $\le$  $x$ $\le$ 9,} \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$ 
>   Find the Cumulative Distribution function and Probability density function of
>   $$Y = \frac {1}{\sqrt{X}}.$$

My **wrong** attempt went as follows:

First I determined the range of $ Y $ to be $y \in [\frac13,1] $ by filling in the boundrairies 1 and 9 into $ Y $

Calculate the CDF by taking the close integral over the interval $ [1,x]$

$$ CDF: \int_1^x \frac18 du =  \frac18(x-1)$$

Then I find CDF of $ Y $  $$  F_y = P(Y \le y )  =  P( \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} \le y ) = P(X \le \frac{1}{y^2} ) = \frac18(\frac{1}{y^2} -1) $$

But this solutions seems to be wrong since it doesn't add up to 1 when integrated over its range $ [\frac13,1]$

If someone could give me an explanaiting where I made an error that be great!

Comment: In the step $\mathbb P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} \le y) = \mathbb P(X \le \frac{1}{y^2})$, Should be $\mathbb P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} \le y) = \mathbb P(X \ge \frac{1}{y^2})$

Comment: Thanks! this results into $ F_Y = \frac{9y}{8} + \frac{1}{8y} + C$ which when integrated over the bound $ [\frac13, 1]$ results in 0.5, does that mean i need to multiply the CDF by a factor 2 since Y only allows positive numbers as input?

Comment: What is that $C$?. $\mathbb P(Y \le y) = 1 - \mathbb P(X < \frac{1}{y^2})$. Now, due to $X$ being continuous r.v, we have $F_Y(y) = 1 - \frac{1}{8}(\frac{1}{y^2}-1) = \frac{9}{8} - \frac{1}{8y^2}$ if $y \in [\frac{1}{3},1]$. It clearly is increasing with limits $0,1$ at $\frac{1}{3},1$. It does not need to integrate to $1$. But, as long as $F_Y$ is piecewise continuosly differentiable (in our case is) we can find a density function just by differentiating CDF. We get $g_Y(y) = \frac{1}{4y^3}$ for $y \in [\frac{1}{3},1]$. And it integrates to one, cause $\int \frac{dy}{4y^3} = \frac{-1}{8y^2}$

Comment: Shouldn't $f_X(x)=1/9$ when $1\le x \le 9$ ?

Comment: @DominikKutek Maybe you could copy your comment into an answer.

Comment: @BernardMassé No, pdf of a Uniform(a,b) variable is $f(x)=1/(b-a)$ whenever $a\le x\le b$ and $0$ otherwise. This makes $f$ integrate to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake is in the line $\mathbb P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} \le y) = \mathbb P(X \le \frac{1}{y^2}),$ because due to $\sqrt{X},y > 0$, we have:

$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} \le y  \iff 1 \le \sqrt{X}y \iff \frac{1}{y} \le \sqrt{X} \iff \frac{1}{y^2} \le X,$ so it should be $P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} \le y) = \mathbb P(X \ge \frac{1}{y^2})$

As you calculated $F_X(t) = \frac{x-1}{8}\chi_{[1,9]}(t) $ and correcting your error, we get $($for $y \in [\frac{1}{3},1])$:

$F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} \le y) = \mathbb P(X \ge \frac{1}{y^2}) = 1 - \mathbb P(X < \frac{1}{y^2}) = 1 - \mathbb P(X \le \frac{1}{y^2}) = 1 - F_X(\frac{1}{y^2}) = 1 - \frac{1}{8}(\frac{1}{y^2}-1) = \frac{1}{8}(9-\frac{1}{y^2}) $

So we get the CDF of $Y$: $F_Y(t) = \frac{1}{8}(9-\frac{1}{t^2})\chi_{[\frac{1}{3},1]}(t)$

Now PDF, as we know since CDF is continuosly differentiable (piecewise at least) it holds, that $f_Y(y) = F_Y'(y)$ for every point in which $F_Y'$ exists (we can put whatever we want in the rest, since $PDF$ is up to the set of measure zero).

Differentiating gives us PDF : $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{4y^3} \chi_{(\frac{1}{3},1)}(y)$ (Note that you could have included points $\frac{1}{3}$ and/or $1$ in characteristic function.